# Resource for (String) Symmetry Breaking in Terms of Roots and Weights?

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, symmetry, group-theory, symmetry-breaking

I'm currently searching, for quite a while now, for a paper/book that discusses  symmetry breaking in terms of roots and weights.

**Any suggestions would be much appreciated!**

Comment: I know of no resource, so just a nitpick on terminology: Roots are *not* generators, they live in the dual of the Cartan subalgebra, not in the whole Lie algebra (or its dual).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Firstly, simply laced algebras are self dual and in physics we deal almost exclusively with simply laced algebras. Secondly, roots *are* generators. We label the elements of each representation by the Cartan generator eigenvalues. This gives us, in general, the weights that define the representation. For the adjoint rep the weights are called roots. The adjoint rep is the rep on the groups own Lie algebra and therefore roots are generators